# smtplib for Python getting hung up on TLS occasionally as of recent

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi2, smtplib, starttls

I've been having quite a peculiar and frustrating issue.
I'm using the raspberry pi and smtplib along with googles smtp servers (port 587) to send out automated emails.

I say peculiar and frustrating because this script has worked up until I tested it yesterday (unrelated testing with the rest of the script, just noticed email was not being sent).

Even more interesting, the script still works *sometimes*, but it is not consistent. I'm 99% sure it is not a connection issue as I am right next to the WiFi access point. The script works on Windows with no issue and doesn't get hung up.

I've enabled smtp debugging on both Windows and Raspberry pi and the only visible difference is during the ehlo, windows shows the computers domain name and the raspberry pi shows a loopback ip address (127.0.1.1). Other than that, the logs are no different (When the raspberry pi script actually works).

To me, it looks like its getting hung up on TLS for some reason, but other times it doesn't?

Below is the smtp/email portion of the script that I am running:

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders

username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = 'MyPassWord'

def emailFile():
    ping = os.system('ping 8.8.8.8')
    try:
        if ping == 0:

            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['Subject'] = "Test Results"
            msg['From'] = username
            msg['To'] = username

            body = "Attached are the results from tests"

            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
            part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(open("C:\Users\sjo\coding\ssidTest.txt", "rb").read())

            #on the pi, the path is different, but the email is being built properly, its the smtp part..

            Encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="ssid.txt"')

            msg.attach(part)

            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
            server.set_debuglevel(1)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.login(username, password)
            server.sendmail(username, username, msg.as_string())
            server.quit()
        else:
            pass
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        pass
        #os.system('sudo reboot now') --- actual exception action. Modified to run on windows..

emailFile()
```

As mentioned above, sometimes the script works and sends, and sometimes it gets hung up and sometimes doesn't display any debug info. However, I was able to run it enough times to witness all scenarios and gather the debug data..

Traceback when the script doesn't display debug info:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python eTest.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "eTest.py", line 31, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:586')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256 in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 317 in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 361 in __init__
    line = se;f.file.readline(_MAXLINE +1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 476 in __init__
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Debug data when the script gets hung up (I'm assuming hung up on tls..)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python eTest.py
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 35882577\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: '250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]
SIZE 35882577
8BITMIME
STARTTLS
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
PIPELINING
CHUNKING
SMTPUTF8
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "eTest.py", line 34, in <module>
    server.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 645, in starttls
    (resp, reply) = self.docmd("STARTTLS")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 361, in getreply
    line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

One time it threw an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python eTest.py
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 35882577\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: '250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]
SIZE 35882577
8BITMIME
STARTTLS
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
PIPELINING
CHUNKING
SMTPUTF8
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eTest.py", line 34, in <module>
    server.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 649, in starttls
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, keyfile, certfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 891, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 566, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 788, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:581)
```

And when its working normally:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python eTest.py
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 35882577\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: '250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]
SIZE 35882577
8BITMIME
STARTTLS
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
PIPELINING
CHUNKING
SMTPUTF8
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 35882577\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: '250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]
SIZE 35882577
8BITMIME
AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
PIPELINING
CHUNKING
SMTPUTF8
send: 'AUTH PLAIN AHB5dGhvbi5waW5nLnRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29tAFA0dGgwTipwIU5n\r\n'
reply: '235 2.7.0 Accepted\r\n'
reply: retcode (235); Msg: 2.7.0 Accepted
send: 'mail FROM:<python.ping.test@gmail.com> size=2253\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.0 OK b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 OK b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp
send: 'rcpt TO:<python.ping.test@gmail.com>\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.5 OK b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.5 OK b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: '354  Go ahead b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: Go ahead b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp
data: (354, 'Go ahead b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp')
send: 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1944471981=="\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nSubject: GPS/WiFi data from: GPS Pilot\r\nFrom: python.ping.test@gmail.com\r\nTo: python.ping.test@gmail.com\r\n\r\n--===============1944471981==\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nGPS/WiFi data attached..\r\n--===============1944471981==\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nContent-Disposition:

 #OMITTED -- info on the attachment and encoding

reply: '250 2.0.0 OK 1460726677 b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 OK 1460726677 b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp
data: (250, '2.0.0 OK 1460726677 b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp')
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: '221 2.0.0 closing connection b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: 2.0.0 closing connection b130sm25543828ywa.7 - gsmtp
```

I read that Google had an 18 minute outage this passed monday, could that have something to do with this? Why would it not work 100% of the time?

Comment: Have you seen any repeat behavior with hangups? If it just happened that one day then I'd assume that it was Google's outage at fault. Otherwise it's probably time to look for some other causes.

Comment: @WayneWerner I noticed it yesterday (I did no testing with it monday-wednesday of this week, so I can't speak for those days). Today, it looked as if everything was back to normal, but then the hangups started occuring again. Sometimes the script will work 5-6 times in a row and then hangup after.

Comment: Well, then it's safe to rule out Google's outage. Are you sure you're not running into some sort of rate limiting?

Comment: @WayneWerner I thought that may have been the case, but I read that google has a pretty high daily limit. And that wouldn't explain the previous, flawless, performance with the smtp operation prior to this week

Comment: You may also look at your own ISP... then again if the Windows box is mailing fine that would be surprising.